# Administrate texts from a symfony system

Tags: php, symfony, text

I'm working on a project which implied to administrate parts of texts from an admin section.

The admin users must be able to change some parts of textes displayed either on front of the website (such as messages on different places) but also in pdf documents generated by the server (certificates, etc.), and also mails.

Some of them must be modified with simple input texts, and other with Wysiwyg.

I've been searching for hours a good solution to do this, but I can't figure out how I can handle this.

The back-end is on a Symfony 3.4 / No front framework is used.

Comment: There is no one line of code or a package that would magically solve this for you. That's what web developers do for living, design solutions to problems like this. You could implement a sort of "Administratable" interface which would be implemented to entities that contain text that needs to be updated, then you would need an actual logic that manipulates Administratable entities in a way you deem desirable. Would it be a command or a controller with a view, it's all up to you.

Comment: Hire a Symfony developer :-)

Comment: For Wysiwyg you can use FOS CK EDITOR BUNDLE and for simple texts you can use SonataAdmin + some of translation bundles. (you can use translation bundle, for storing texts with ease)

Answer (score 0):

You need a symfony based CMS, did you look at Victoire.io ?https://packagist.org/packages/victoire/victoire#2.3.36